# Why am I getting Indy EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError Exception

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

All of a sudden on a development computer I periodically get **EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError** exceptions when making https calls using the **TIdHTTP.get** procedure.  The exact message is:

```
Error connecting with SSL. Error connecting with SSL. error:1408E0F4:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_MESSAGE:unexpected message
```

Now what is interesting is that it only happens on one computer.  Everything works fine on other computers.  It is like SSL is broken on development computer.   I don't think it is a coding issue.  Things had worked fine before, and as I said, I can take the application to another computer and everything works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: That is an error from OpenSSL itself. I have never seen that error before. You may have to ask about it on the OpenSSL developer mailing list.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thank you.  Figured something like this.  I always thought incorrectly OpenSSL was needed only for server (TIdHTTPServer).  Please move this to an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an error from OpenSSL itself. I have never seen that particular error message before. You may have to ask about it on the OpenSSL developer mailing list.  In the meantime, make sure OpenSSL is installed correctly, or at least copy the OpenSSL DLLs from a working computer to your app's folder.  And thn use a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark, to verify the communication is actually SSL encrypted properly.

Comment: Turns out an incorrect version of OpenSSL was installed.  Simply re-installing the correct version corrected the problem.  Thank you very much!